# All jobs show “Oops! Something Bad Happened!”

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Currently, clicking on any job shows the error “Oops! Something Bad Happened!.

For example, click on any job on [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=php&tl=php%20yii&v=true&t=true).

Removing the `a` parameter from the beginning (e.g. `a=Q8RdrxsU1i0`) makes the job page appear normally; i.e., instead of

`https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/155479/senior-php-developer-docler-holding?a=Q8RdrxsU1i0&so=i&pg=1&offset=-1&total=72&q=php&t=true&v=true&tl=php+yii`

navigating to

`https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/155479/senior-php-developer-docler-holding?so=i&pg=1&offset=-1&total=72&q=php&t=true&v=true&tl=php+yii`

works fine.

Comment: The job section is coded in PHP?

Comment: I can confirm. Every single job link that I clicked is returning me the "Oops!" error.

Comment: Can confirm the same error on my side.

Comment: Confirmed on mobile as well.

Comment: I’ve tried to remove the parameter from each link programmatically, yet clicking on them still produces the error, but copy-pasting the exact same URL works. That’s strange.

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks for the report - a Redis server failed; SREs have been working on it for the past few hours, all requests should be hitting a backup server now.

Comment: Or maybe you just passed the first technical test! ;)

Comment: Not showing errors now for me at least

Comment: Even the wrong link is working in my case.

Comment: All link works fine !